# Combinatorial characterizations of potentially countably chromatic graphs

Tags: set-theory, forcing, infinite-combinatorics

Is there a combinatorial characterization of (uncountably chromatic) graphs that are "potentially" countably chromatic? By this I mean: $G=(V,E)$ is a graph such that there exists a cardinal preserving forcing $\mathbb{P}$ such that $\Vdash_{\mathbb{P}} \chi(G)\leq \aleph_0$ ($\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number of $G$). (some easy examples are ruled out easily, like graphs that have $K_{\aleph_1}$ or those already countably chromatic in the ground)

Comment: I am not aware of a characterization, but since you mentioned some easy examples, let me point out that a few more may be found in here: http://www.assafrinot.com/paper/17.

Comment: It seems that to get a good answer you might have to narrow your search to a particular class of graphs.  In this direction let me point out that the Open Coloring Axiom (aka Todorcevic's Axiom or the Open Graph Dichotomy) says exactly that every graph on a separable metrizable space, whose edge set is open, falls into one of your two easily ruled-out classes.  So there are no potentially countably-chromatic graphs in that class, assuming OCA.

Comment: (Note also that you can force OCA from any model of ZFC, but it does exactly what you don't want, i.e. given an open graph on a separable metrizable space with uncountable chromatic number, the OCA forcing will produce an uncountable clique.)

Comment: Since the dual coloring axiom fails for the class of closed graphs, maybe I should think of examples of closed graphs (for graphs on $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: There are also a lot of examples in the literature surrounding graphs of size $< 2^{\aleph_0}$ where the poset of finite cliques is ccc, and of course forcing axioms for these, which are called Ramsey forcing axioms.    See e.g. Todorcevic's book "Partition problems in topology" or Velickovic's paper "Applications of the open coloring axiom".